# Sitecore presentation details rendering datasource is empty

Tags: sitecore8

in the below code the datasource is coming as null for all the renderings present in presentation details, please help me where i am going wrong

```
LayoutDefinition layout = 
LayoutDefinition.Parse(bioItem[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);

foreach (DeviceDefinition device in layout.Devices) {
 if (device.Renderings != null) { 
  for(var i =0; i < device.Renderings.Count;i++) { 
     RenderingDefinition rendering = (RenderingDefinition)device.Renderings[i];     
      var result = rendering.Datasource;
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know there are two layout fields:

- Shared: Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField
- Final:  Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField

i usually use this code snippet to read directly from layout:

```
var devices = dataItem.Database.Resources.Devices;
var defaultDevice = devices.GetAll().First(d => d.Name.ToLower() == ScConstants.DefaultDeviceName);
var renderings = dataItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(defaultDevice, true);
foreach (var rendering in renderings)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rendering?.Settings.DataSource))
    {
     var datasource = dataItem.Database.GetItem(rendering.Settings.DataSource, dataItem.Language);
     .....
```

There are other ways to read the Layout field, but i suggest you to using the provided API and keep the layout XML parsing as the last resort.